# Django ModelForm with ForeignKey

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models, **Item** and **OnHand**. **Item** represents the product, like a USB Keyboard, while **OnHand** represents an actual USB Keyboard.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    vendor_sku = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='000000000')
    replenish_threshold = models.IntegerField(max_length=1000, default=10)
    max_onhand = models.IntegerField(max_length=10000, default=30)
    introduction = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, default=slugify(name))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'items'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OnHand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='Consumable')
    asset = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'items on hand'

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.serial:
            return self.name
        return self.serial
```

---

I have a **ModelForm** I use for adding new **Items** and **OnHand**, the form I'm working with is at */inventory/add_onhand//* so `/inventory/add_onhand/1/` would be the form to add a keyboard to inventory for **Item** with a primary key of 1.

```
class OnHandForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OnHand
        fields = {'name', 'asset', 'serial',}
```

---

```
def add_onhand(request, query):
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = OnHandForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return redirect('view_item')
    else:
        print(query)
        form = OnHandForm()
        item = Item.objects.get(pk=query)
        return render(request, 'add_onhand.html', {'form':form, 'item':item})
```

When saving a new **OnHand** via this form, how would I direct the relationship **to** **Item**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still hoping for a better solution, but in the meantime what I've done was added `product` to the form, but using JQuery to hide the element and automatically select it based on the `Item`'s primary key.

This is hacky, but it works. I'd hope for a more elegant solution.